# Is hidden field better to store value instead of session for long access period of time

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, hidden-field

I wanted to use session to store one important information in it that I need very long (*can't extend session life*).
But session can expire off course :)
Problem is if user sit and do something I set value in session and if he goes off computer and return after few hours to continue this value will be lost.
**My question:**
If I save this value in `hidden field` instead of `session` will it be there forever (*I mean while page is open*)?

PS
I don't have time to test(waiting) that's why I ask :)

Comment: make use of caching...

Comment: If you store it in a hidden field, then yes it will be there forever. But usually when session expires, the user will get redirected to a login page which will cause the hidden field to disappear since you are no longer in the same page. You can try using cookies instead.

Comment: User doesn't have to be logged in for process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, you can go for a `HiddenField`. However, since you will be storing important information, make sure you ENCRYPT the value before assigning it to `HiddenField`. And Yes, this will be present for long.

One fairly good option you can also try is saving your information in `ViewState`. It doesn’t take up any memory on the server and doesn’t impose any arbitrary 
usage limits (such as a time-out ). Moreover you can use the built-in Encryption facility provided by Asp.Net

```
ViewState["UserSSN"] = 1;

if (ViewState["UserSSN"] != null) 
{ 
     _userSSN= (int)ViewState["UserSSN"]; 
}
```

In case you are using `ViewState`, you must take countermeasures for its security. Simply turn on encryption for viewstate using the [**`ViewStateEncryptionMode`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.viewstateencryptionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the Page directive:

```
<%@Page ViewStateEncryptionMode="Always" ... %>
```

Or you can set the same attribute in the `web.config` file:

```
<pages viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" />
```

They aren’t bulletproof, but they will greatly increase the effort an attacker would need in order to read or modify view state data.